# POST with Indy + SSL + Proxy

Tags: delphi, ssl, proxy, indy, idhttp

I'm trying to do a POST request through proxy using https.
Code looks like:

```
  FHttp := TIdHttp.Create(nil);

  FHttp.ProxyParams.ProxyServer := Host;
  FHttp.ProxyParams.ProxyPort := Port;
  FHttp.ProxyParams.ProxyUsername := User;
  FHttp.ProxyParams.ProxyPassword := Password;

  FHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
  FHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1_2;
  FHandler.PassThrough := true;
  FHttp.IOHandler := FHandler;
  FHttp.HandleRedirects := true;
  FHttp.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
  FHttp.Request.Connection := 'keep-alive';
  FHttp.Request.ProxyConnection := 'keep-alive';
...

  FParams.Add('username=user');
  FParams.Add('password=pwd');
  FHttp.Post('https://my.service/login', FParams);
```

Proxy server is Squid.

Code generates error "Socket Error # 10054 Connection reset by peer."

Now, the interesting part comes:

1. If not using proxy at all (i.e. not setting FHttp.ProxyParams settings) - everything is OK.
2. If not setting any POST parameters (i.e. empty FParams), but still **using proxy** - everything is OK.
3. The most strange one: If I'm debugging the Indy code step by step (TIdCustomHTTP.DoRequest method) - everything is OK with above example (proxy settings + parameters).

POST parameters are not sent properly for some reason?

And why step 3 is happening?

Indy is up to date, just pulled from repository

**UPDATE**

After intercepting TIdHTTP calls (thanks [Remy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65863/remy-lebeau)) there is a little bit more clarity. ([failing log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/170beium6QhRnPlo_mOoX9fad5qu6clkB/view?usp=sharing), [working log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10zI3b235LHG4BZGxLzgwyqzkbVMGwiGI/view?usp=sharing)).

Short version: when doing debug, Indy does 3 CONNECT + POST + DISCONNECT requests (because there are redirection on the service I believe) and it works.

When running test without debug - CONNECT + DISCONNECT + POST - and it fails obviously (i.e. POST is executed without CONNECT in front).
See attached log files for details.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Squid, rather than a bug in `TIdHTTP`. The content of the HTTP request is handled completely separate from how the TCP connection to the target server is established. `TIdHTTP` will send the `FParams` in exactly the same way regardless of whether a proxy is used or not (see the calls to `FHTTPProto.BuildAndSendRequest(URL);` and `IOHandler.Write(ARequest.Source, ...)` in `TIdCustomHTTP.ConnectToHost()`, after the proxy connection is ready). #3 also confirms that, since timing does not affect how `TIdHTTP` forms its HTTP requests...

Comment: ... You can also confirm this by assigning a `TIdConnectionIntercept`-based component, such as one of the `TIdLog...` components, to the `TIdHTTP.Intercept` property to see what `TIdHTTP` actually sends, regardless of whether SSL/TLS is used.

Comment: I would agree with you that it's a Squid bug if IXMLHttpRequest (from Winapi.MSXML) wouldn't work properly with proxy settings and parameters set.

Comment: You have found bugs in `TIdHTTP`, after all. I have posted an answer with details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have found some logic bugs in `TIdHTTP` that need to be fixed.  I have opened a new ticket for that:

[#315: Bugs in TIdHTTP proxy handling](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/315)

---

Here is what I see happening in your "failing" scenario:

`TIdHTTP` connects to the proxy, sends a `CONNECT` request that successfully connects to `my.service.com:443`, then sends a `POST` request (using HTTP 1.0 rather than HTTP 1.1 <sup>a</sup>).

<sup>a) to send a `POST` request with HTTP 1.1, you have to set the `TIdHTTP.ProtocolVersion` property to `pv1_1`, AND enable the `hoKeepOrigProtocol` flag in the `TIdHTTP.HTTPOptions` property.  Otherwise, `TIdHTTP.Post()` forces the `ProtocolVersion` to `pv1_0`.</sup>

The HTTP server replies with a `302 Found` response redirecting to a different URL, including a `Keep-Alive` header indicating the server will close the connection if a new request is not sent in the next 5 seconds.

When `TIdHTTP` is done processing the `POST` response, it knows it is going to re-send the same request to a new URL.  On the next loop iteration, it sees that the target server is the same, and the proxy is still connected, and so the connection is not closed, and the code that would have sent a new `CONNECT` request is skipped.

Just before the `POST` request is sent, the `Response.KeepAlive` property is checked to know whether or not to close the socket connection anyway.  The `KeepAlive` property getter sees the `ProtocolVersion` property is `pv1_0` and that there is no `Proxy-Connection: keep-alive` header present in the response (even though there is a `Connection: keep-alive` header), so it returns False, and then the socket connection is closed.

`TIdHTTP` then re-connects to the proxy again, but does not send a new `CONNECT` request before sending the `POST` request.  The proxy does not know what to do with the `POST`, so it fails the request with a `400 Bad Request` response.

---

Here is what I see happening in your "working" scenario:

Everything is the same as above, up to the point where the 1st `POST` request is processed.  Then there is a delay of roughly 16 seconds (likely since you are stepping through code) - more than the 5-second `Keep-Alive` delay allows - so the HTTP server closes its connection with the proxy, which then closes its connection to `TIdHTTP`.

By the time `TIdHTTP` is ready to send the 2nd `POST` request, it knows it has been disconnected from the proxy, so it re-connects to the proxy, sends a new `CONNECT` request, and then sends the `POST` request.

---

Until I can fix the bugs properly, try the following:

- enable the `hoKeepOrigProtocol` flag in the `TIdHTTP.HTTPOptions` property to allow `TIdHTTP.Post()` to use HTTP 1.1.  That in itself may fix the issue with the connection being closed unnecessarily before sending the 2nd `POST` request to the redirected URL.
- if that doesn't solve the issue, try editing `IdHTTP.pas` yourself and recompile Indy, to update the `TIdCustomHTTP.ConnectToHost()` method to force a `Disconnect()` if the `Response.KeepAlive` property is False *BEFORE* the local `LUseConnectVerb` variable is set to `not Connected` in the case where `ARequest.UseProxy` is `ctSSLProxy` (and `ctProxy`, too).  That way, the 2nd `POST` request will disconnect from the proxy and re-connect with a new `CONNECT` request.

Comment: First option (adding hoKeepOrigProtocol to HTTPOptions) did the trick. Thanks!